# why doesn't regex match the text?

Tags: regex

I've got the regex.

```
Pay a\s(.+)\sunit loan with %(.+)\sinterest and\s(.+)\spayments from\s(.+)\sto\s(.+)\s\.
```

and I'm trying to match it with:

> Pay a 50 unit loan with %17 interest and 12 payments from melli to mika the real kaka.

But they don't match.why is it so? and do you have any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't (fully) match because you're looking for a whitespace, followed by any character other than a whitespace (`\s.`), so that's where it stops. You need to escape the dot to actually find it - `\s.+\.` (look for a whitespace, followed by any character, followed by a dot). [Example](https://regexr.com/50t1f)

```
Pay a\s(.+)\sunit loan with %(.+)\sinterest and\s(.+)\spayments from\s(.+)\sto\s(.+)\s.+\.
```

But regardless of that - you're already matching everything after the last whitespace - so the `\s.` in the end of the regex is redundant.

Just remove the `\s.` from the end of the regex ([Example](https://regexr.com/50t1i))

```
Pay a\s(.+)\sunit loan with %(.+)\sinterest and\s(.+)\spayments from\s(.+)\sto\s(.+)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are wrong, because the pattern *matches* the string, but not the whole.

Your misunderstanding lies in the end of the pattern: `to\s(.+)\s.` matches:

`to` - literally `to`

`\s` - whitespace, space in your string

`(.+)` - 1+ of any characters, as much as it can (greedy), so it matches `mika the real`

`\s` - again, a whitespace, matches a space

`.` - any character (just one), matches `k`

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ens5M9/1).

If you omit last `\s`, it will match entire string. [Working example](https://regex101.com/r/Ens5M9/2).